# equation by parts?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces, vectors

I was doing vectors and encountered an exercise in which it says ''write down the equation by parts of the plane'' what does it mean ''equation by parts of the plane''?

Answer (score 1):

Probably it means the equations
$$
\Pi:\begin{cases}x=x_0+\lambda v_x+\mu u_x,\\
y=y_0+\lambda v_y+\mu u_y, \\
z=z_0+\lambda v_z+ \mu u_z,
\end{cases}
$$
where $(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in \Pi$ and $u,v$ are two linearly independent vectors tangent to the plane.